# How can I install a new lighting circuit in my kitchen?

Tags: electrical

I would like to install 2 new light fixtures and a switch in my kitchen. Currently the kitchen has three lights each controlled by their own switch. I want the new lights to have their own switch located next to one of the other switches. I am trying to figure out the best and easiest way to to get power to the lights? A diagram of the required wiring would be helpful.

Comment: A diagram of your current wiring would be helpful.

Comment: The difficulty is that there are alternative possible wiring schemes for the existing lights. Is the line power coming through the switch and then to the lights or directly to the lights with a switch loop (or a combination among the existing lights)? Pictures of the wiring in the existing switch boxes and the boxes holding the lights may give us enough info to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can in all likelihood run it off your existing circuit, but without knowing the current layout it is hard to say for sure.

You are probably better off hiring an electrician. Doing work like this requires significantly more information and technique than can be explained in a forum post or single diagram.

I am a firm believer in DIY, self-reliant amateur electricians, but just reading a few posts on a forum does not cut it. You need to have and use books that explain in detail the correct procedures, otherwise you could make serious errors with potentially dangerous ramifications.

If you have a specific problem, by all means bring it to the exchange, but just asking, "How do I wire up a whole circuit?" is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a new line from your electrical box for the switch box and the lights.

you could come off an existing circuit that is not over the fixture/power draw limit.

What is easiest depends on what you have and what you know.

Do you want the new lights each one their own switch or is it a shared switch? 
Are you increasing the size of the switch plate box? there are some switches that can put 2 in one spot and that may be easier, more so if you can share electrical load.

It would be easiest for you to draw a diagram of what you have then you can be told more succinctly how to add to it.